# Number of digits after multiplication, dividing

Tags: c#, math, multiplication

I have two numbers **X** and **Y**, i don't know their values but i know that the maximal number of digits that can contain ***X*** is 10 (for example) and for ***Y*** is 3 (for example)

I need to know the maximal number of digits of **Z** that equals to **X * Y**. Same for **Z = X / Y**

Comment: this would help to get the number of digits [How can I get a count of the total number of digits in a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483886/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-the-total-number-of-digits-in-a-number)

Comment: Are we talking integers or floating point values here?

Comment: for multiplication the maximum digits will be there when both X and Y will be maximum..for above case `X = 99999999999` and `Y = 999`..for division X should be maximum and Y minimum...`X = 9999999999` and `Y = 100`

Comment: according to your question it says that what is the maximal number of digits `Z` can have..so we have to assume the worst case that `X` and `Y` can have..but for fractional numbers it will not be valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `X` can have at most `n` digits and `Y` can have at most `m` digits, then

> X < 10 ^ n and Y < 10 ^ m

This means that

> X * Y < 10 ^ n * 10 ^ m = 10 ^ (n + m)

In other words,

> X * Y can have at most n + m digits.

With division, we need to take the worst case for `Y` - that is value 1. So maximum number of digits for `X / Y` is `n`.

However, if you know Y has exactly m digits, then we can say that

> Y >= 10 ^ (m - 1)

in that case we get:

> X / Y < (10 ^ n) / (10 ^ (m-1)) => X / Y < (10 ^ (n - m + 1))

This means that `X / Y` has at most `n - m + 1` digits when Y has exactly m digits.

Answer (score 2):

assume the number of digit in `X` is `n` and for `Y` is `m` and **values are rounded** so

the maximum number of digits in `(x*y)` is `n+m` and

the maximum number of digits in `(x/y)` is `n-m+1`

Comment: Not correct for Y=1 - in that case X/Y can have at most n digits.

Comment: for Y = 1 `z = n - 1 + 1 = n` which is correct i think