# Missing something in my C# count for integers code

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, character, counting

I'm doing some excercises for school and ran into a problem.
When I try to count the characters in a array it just gives back the array itself.
Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? The code is in C#.

```
public static int CountFor(int n)
{
        int count = 0;

        int[] a = new int[] {n};
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            count += i;
        }
        return count;
}
```

and in the main to show the results:

```
Console.WriteLine(CountFor(1024));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Visual Studio has a built-in debugger which works faster, more accurate and more satisfying than posting on Stack Overflow. Place a breakpoint (F9) and step through your code (F10) and inspect your variables to see what your code is doing. The code `a = new int[] {n}` is not doing what you expect it to, which is the root cause of your issue. By inspecting it, you could have falsified your problem statement of _"it just gives back the array itself"_, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
new int[] {n}
```

to

```
new int[n]
```

With `new int[] {n}`, you have an array with `1` element as `n`.

Read: [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You can easily use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) methods to simplify your method like;

```
public static int CountFor(int n)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(1, n).Sum();
}
```

Comment: But  the console gives back 523776 while it's supposed to give back 4 as 1024 contains 4 integers. Can you explain this?

Comment: @Johan your code adds `1+2+3+...+1024`. You can find this out for yourself by using the debugger. If you want to count the number of digits in an integer, that's a different question, which is answered in [How can I get a count of the total number of digits in a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483886/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-the-total-number-of-digits-in-a-number).

Comment: Thanks again, I can figure the rest out myself like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `new int[n]`, otherwise you are generating a new array with length 1 with the passed integer as the *content* of the array