# int array cannot use length property inside linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have this very simple c# statement

```
       var list = new int[4];

        var query1 = from element in list
                     where element.Length > 10
                     select element;
```

and for some reason it's not letting me use Length property of int array and throwing me a following exception:

```
'int' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 
'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (press F4 
to add a using directive or assembly reference)
```

i cannot figure what's going on. if i write the following:

```
 var query1 = from element in list.Length
                     where element > 10
                     select element;
```

then it works.

Comment: The query iterates through all elements of `list`. Those elements are of type `int` not of type `int[]`.

Comment: What are you trying to get as a result?

Comment: nothing. i was playing with linq expressions and converting from string array to int array i started having this issue and did not realise till i received the answers from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your query:

```
   var list = new int[4];

    var query1 = from element in list
                 where element.Length > 10
                 select element;
```

Here the `element` is an individual `integer` from the array `list`and not a `int[]`. So obviously `Length` doesn't exist for `int` type.

Answer (score 2):

`from element` means that linq is going to loop over all `int`s in list and every `int` is from then on called element.

See it as a foreach loop. You now wrote something like this:

```
foreach(int element in list)
{
    if(element.Length > 10) // an int doesn't have a Length property
    {
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the length property, but this is what you wrote. Could you describe what you want to assess with the length property?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you write `from element in list` you say that you want to enumerate over each element of `list` so `element` is of type `int`. No `Length` property on `int` type exists. Hence the error.
2. When you write `from element in list.Length` you want to enumerate over single item which is the length of the array and that item is of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`element` is an `int` retrieved from the array `list`. It isn't the array itself.

Since `int` doesn't have a `Length` property, it doesn't work. If you are looking for the number of digits of the integer, take a look here: [How can I get a count of the total number of digits in a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4483886/993547).

The end result would be:

```
var list = new int[4];

var query1 = from element in list
             where (element == 0 ? 1 : Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(element)) + 1)) > 10
             select element;
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: `Math.Log10(element)` will fail on *zero* and *negative items*; `var list = new int[] {0, -1, -2, -3};`

Comment: A subtle error: `Math.Abs(element)` can fail on `element == int.MinValue` (integer overflow error)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right: `int` doesn't have any `Length` property (and `list` is an array of `int`s). Do you mean *string representation* of `int`?

```
var list = new int[4];
...

var query = list
  .Where(element => element.ToString().Length > 10) // note "ToString()"
  .Select(element);
```

Please note, that the query, probably, will return `an empty enumerable`: the longest string representation of `int` in most cultures is `-2147483648` which has *exactly 10 digits*. If you want count digits (e.g. `-123` has three digits)
you can modify the query a little:

```
var query = list
  .Where(element => element
    .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .Trim('-')
    .Length > 10) 
  .Select(element);
```

And in this case, you will *definitely* have an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is similar to this:

```
var list = new int[4];            
var filteredElements = new List<int>();
foreach (int element in list)
{
  if(element.Length > 10)
  {
    filteredElements.Add(element);
  }
}
```

That's why you get error 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method