# Making 2 ints merge but with the highest number in first spot and the lowest in the back

Tags: c#

**I would like to make my 2 ints get together in one number but where the biggest of the 2 get in the front and the other one in the back**

I have a var named num1 and one named num2.
The numbers of those 2 are getting assigned thru a random.
I would like to make them into one number but with the highest number first and the other one after it. I don't want to + them together but make a big number.

For example num1 = 5 and num2 = 6 my whole number should then be 65.

Thx in advance I tried googling this but I could not really find what I was. Looking for sry for bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution i used a little of both of your answers 
This is what it ended like

```
        num1 = randomNum.Next(1, 7);
        num2 = randomNum.Next(1, 7);
        maxNum = Math.Max(num1, num2);
        minNum = Math.Min(num1, num2);
        wholeNum = minNum + 10 * maxNum;`
```

Answer (score 4):

Utilise `Math.Max` and `Math.Min` to find the largest and smallest of the two numbers, then concatenate and parse to an `int`.

```
int result = int.Parse(Math.Max(num1, num2) + ""+  Math.Min(num1, num2));
```

or if the number can get large after concatenation then use the `long` data type.

```
long result = long.Parse(Math.Max(num1, num2) + ""+  Math.Min(num1, num2));
```

Comment: Why do you suggest stringly typed code?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=stringly+typed+code ... You should not recommend anti-patterns even if OP demonstrated no efforts including no understanding of `if`... (and just in case if you don't think OP knows how to count digits - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483886/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-the-total-number-of-digits-in-a-number or how to deal with big integer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you wish to randomly generate the digits separately, then combine the digits to form a two-digit number. So:

```
var num1 = 5;
var num2 = 6;
var bigNumber = num1 + 10 * num2;  //65
```

Comment: Its not working