# Is there an efficient way to get the length of a BigInteger without calling ToString?

Tags: c#, biginteger

Consider the following code:

```cs
BigInteger value = BigInteger.Parse("9876543210987654321098765432109876543210");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString().Length); // 40
```

Is there a more efficient way to get the length of the number without calling `ToString`?

Comment: you know about int128? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0

Comment: @RandRandom That's only available in .NET 7 which isn't out yet, and still doesn't answer the question :)

Comment: Have you tried `BigInteger.Log(value, 10.0)`?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk isn't that a heavier task to do than `ToString`?

Comment: @AndreasM: possibly.

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to be more efficient with... memory or processor time. `BigInteger.Log` does some bit manipulation and then calls `Math.Log`. No string allocation/construction, less memory, but possibly more processing time depending on the cost of the `Math.Log` calls.

Comment: This is going to be fundamentally the same question and advice as any other number type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483886/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-the-total-number-of-digits-in-a-number, it being a BigInteger doesn't really matter. You have your choice of [log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483960/1043380) or [ToString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4483910/1043380).

Comment: As for which is more efficient... benchmark, benchmark, benchmark!

Comment: I didn't actually think about CPU vs. memory... doh!

Comment: Also, not sure if `BigInteger.Log(value, 10.0)` is the same as `BigInteger.Log10(value)` or not, the latter may have been optimised differently (or not!)

Comment: It is. It calls `Log(value, 10.0)`. That's the entirety of `BigInteger.Log10`'s implementation, at least in .NET 6.

Comment: But, but, but, it's less code to write!

Comment: Matthew Layton what is the expected value for the length of `BigInteger.Parse("-1")`? Is it 1 or 2?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias for my use-case, that would be 1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Anytime a question asks about "performance", it is always necessary to benchmark the approaches. As madreflection pointed out, there is both cpu and memory costs to consider, so I ran benchmarks targeting .NET 6 with a memory diagnoser. The results are fascinating and Joel's answer performs very poorly compared to the highly optimized `ToString()` and `Log10` methods of `BigInteger`.

**Benchmark Code**:

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class BigIntegerBenchmarks
{
    private static BigInteger _value = BigInteger.Parse("9876543210987654321098765432109876543210");

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public int ToStringBenchmark()
    {
        return _value.ToString().Length;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int GetLengthDivisionBenchmark()
    {
        return GetLengthDivision(_value);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark()
    {
        return GetLengthMultiplication(_value);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark()
    {
        return GetLengthAbsPow(_value);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int BigIntegerLog()
    {
        return (int)Math.Round(BigInteger.Log10(_value), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int CountDigitsBenchmark()
    {
        return CountDigits(_value);
    }

    static int GetLengthDivision(BigInteger value)
    {
        int result = 1;
        while (value >= 10)
        {
            result++;
            value /= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static int GetLengthMultiplication(BigInteger value)
    {
        BigInteger power = 10;
        int result = 1;
        while (power < value)
        {
            result++;
            power *= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static int GetLengthAbsPow(BigInteger value)
    {
        int result = 1;
        BigInteger ten = new(10);
        BigInteger absValue = BigInteger.Abs(value);

        while (BigInteger.Pow(ten, result) < absValue)
        {
            result++;
        }

        return result;
    }

    internal static int CountDigits(BigInteger value)
    {
        int num = 1;
        BigInteger num2;
        if (value >= 10000000)
        {
            if (value >= 100000000000000L)
            {
                num2 = value / 100000000000000;
                num += 14;

                while (num2 >= 10)
                {
                    num++;
                    num2 /= 10;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                num2 = value / 10000000;
                num += 7;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            num2 = (uint)value;
        }
        if (num2 >= 10)
        {
            num = ((num2 < 100) ? (num + 1) : ((num2 < 1000) ? (num + 2) : ((num2 < 10000) ? (num + 3) : ((num2 < 100000) ? (num + 4) : ((num2 >= 1000000) ? (num + 6) : (num + 5))))));
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

**Results:**

```ini
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1826 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i7-8565U CPU 1.80GHz (Whiskey Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=7.0.100-preview.4.22252.9
  [Host]   : .NET Core 3.1.24 (CoreCLR 4.700.22.16002, CoreFX 4.700.22.17909), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET 6.0 : .NET 6.0.5 (6.0.522.21309), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET 6.0  Runtime=.NET 6.0
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ToStringBenchmark | 160.96 ns | 3.200 ns | 2.837 ns | 1.00 | 0.00 | 0.0668 | 280 B |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 1,939.93 ns | 35.299 ns | 31.292 ns | 12.06 | 0.28 | 0.3052 | 1,288 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 1,330.02 ns | 21.522 ns | 20.131 ns | 8.26 | 0.17 | 0.5569 | 2,336 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 10,928.05 ns | 123.547 ns | 115.566 ns | 67.89 | 1.25 | 3.4637 | 14,520 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 58.34 ns | 1.179 ns | 0.985 ns | 0.36 | 0.01 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 1,018.92 ns | 9.688 ns | 8.589 ns | 6.33 | 0.12 | 0.1774 | 744 B |

[image]

**Notes**:

- CountDigits is a clever method from System.Buffers.Text.FormattingHelpers that I adapted for BigInteger. It performs significantly better than Joel's methods, but far worse than either ToString or Log10.
- Matthew's adapted method was 5-10x worse than Joel's method, showing just how important benchmarking code can be when selecting an algorithm.

**Conclusion**:

`BigInteger.Log10()` seems to be by far the fastest method and causes zero memory allocations, although the need to round concerns me. You would have to determine if that rounding method is acceptable to you and worth the risk.

In addition, it is worth noting that the dotnet core team and open source community continue to heavily optimize the framework apis and runtime. It is critical to prove that they do in fact have a slow algorithm via benchmarking before rolling your own solution.

---

To Theodor Zoulias' point, the benchmarks against a single value are incomplete.

As a result, I ran additional benchmarks against BigInteger values ranging from 10 digits to 200 digits. In all cases, the winner was consistently the `Log10` implementation. For very small numbers (10 digits) the `CountDigits` implementation beats `ToString` but not `Log10`.

**Benchmark Code:**

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class BigIntegerBenchmarks
{        
    public IEnumerable<BigInteger> Values()
    {
        // 10
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("1234512345");
        // 20
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("12345123451234512345");
        // 30
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("123451234512345123451234512345");
        // 40
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("1234512345123451234512345123451234512345");
        // 50
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("12345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345");
        // 75
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345");
        // 100
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("1234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345");
        // 150
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345");
        // 200
        yield return BigInteger.Parse("12345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345");
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Values))]
    public int ToStringBenchmark(BigInteger value)
    {
        return value.ToString().Length;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Values))]
    public int GetLengthDivisionBenchmark(BigInteger value)
    {
        return GetLengthDivision(value);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Values))]
    public int GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark(BigInteger value)
    {
        return GetLengthMultiplication(value);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Values))]
    public int GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark(BigInteger value)
    {
        return GetLengthAbsPow(value);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Values))]
    public int BigIntegerLog(BigInteger value)
    {
        return (int)Math.Floor(BigInteger.Log10(value) + 1);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Values))]
    public int CountDigitsBenchmark(BigInteger value)
    {
        return CountDigits(value);
    }

    static int GetLengthDivision(BigInteger value)
    {
        int result = 1;
        while (value >= 10)
        {
            result++;
            value /= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static int GetLengthMultiplication(BigInteger value)
    {
        BigInteger power = 10;
        int result = 1;
        while (power < value)
        {
            result++;
            power *= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }

    static int GetLengthAbsPow(BigInteger value)
    {
        int result = 1;
        BigInteger ten = new(10);
        BigInteger absValue = BigInteger.Abs(value);

        while (BigInteger.Pow(ten, result) < absValue)
        {
            result++;
        }

        return result;
    }

    internal static int CountDigits(BigInteger value)
    {
        int num = 1;
        BigInteger num2;
        if (value >= 10000000)
        {
            if (value >= 100000000000000L)
            {
                num2 = value / 100000000000000;
                num += 14;

                while (num2 >= 10)
                {
                    num++;
                    num2 /= 10;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                num2 = value / 10000000;
                num += 7;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            num2 = (uint)value;
        }
        if (num2 >= 10)
        {
            num = ((num2 < 100) ? (num + 1) : ((num2 < 1000) ? (num + 2) : ((num2 < 10000) ? (num + 3) : ((num2 < 100000) ? (num + 4) : ((num2 >= 1000000) ? (num + 6) : (num + 5))))));
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

**Results:**

```ini
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1826 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i7-8565U CPU 1.80GHz (Whiskey Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=7.0.100-preview.4.22252.9
  [Host]   : .NET Core 3.1.24 (CoreCLR 4.700.22.16002, CoreFX 4.700.22.17909), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET 6.0 : .NET 6.0.5 (6.0.522.21309), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET 6.0  Runtime=.NET 6.0
```

| Method | value | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **1234512345** | **53.48 ns** | **1.085 ns** | **1.333 ns** | **53.10 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.0114** | **48 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 1234512345 | 160.13 ns | 2.436 ns | 2.991 ns | 159.68 ns | 3.00 | 0.09 | - | - |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 1234512345 | 130.25 ns | 2.035 ns | 1.904 ns | 129.94 ns | 2.42 | 0.07 | 0.0076 | 32 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 1234512345 | 1,602.62 ns | 14.585 ns | 13.643 ns | 1,603.14 ns | 29.79 | 0.76 | 0.3567 | 1,496 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 1234512345 | 23.52 ns | 0.148 ns | 0.123 ns | 23.53 ns | 0.44 | 0.01 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 1234512345 | 30.82 ns | 0.523 ns | 1.274 ns | 30.50 ns | 0.60 | 0.03 | - | - |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **12345123451234512345** | **96.01 ns** | **1.962 ns** | **1.927 ns** | **95.17 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.0440** | **184 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 12345123451234512345 | 609.47 ns | 11.889 ns | 9.928 ns | 608.20 ns | 6.32 | 0.13 | 0.0763 | 320 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 12345123451234512345 | 568.80 ns | 8.009 ns | 7.100 ns | 566.88 ns | 5.91 | 0.15 | 0.1717 | 720 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 12345123451234512345 | 4,795.50 ns | 74.831 ns | 62.487 ns | 4,796.57 ns | 49.75 | 1.01 | 1.0910 | 4,584 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 12345123451234512345 | 43.85 ns | 0.565 ns | 0.441 ns | 43.79 ns | 0.46 | 0.01 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 12345123451234512345 | 156.70 ns | 1.055 ns | 0.881 ns | 156.89 ns | 1.63 | 0.04 | 0.0153 | 64 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **12345(...)12345 [30]** | **130.06 ns** | **0.931 ns** | **0.825 ns** | **130.38 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.0572** | **240 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [30] | 1,196.23 ns | 8.965 ns | 7.486 ns | 1,199.23 ns | 9.20 | 0.08 | 0.1888 | 792 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [30] | 926.82 ns | 13.441 ns | 11.915 ns | 927.25 ns | 7.13 | 0.12 | 0.3557 | 1,488 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [30] | 9,131.78 ns | 324.146 ns | 955.750 ns | 8,980.04 ns | 61.96 | 2.28 | 2.1362 | 8,944 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 12345(...)12345 [30] | 43.73 ns | 0.673 ns | 0.597 ns | 43.61 ns | 0.34 | 0.01 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [30] | 546.94 ns | 10.446 ns | 11.611 ns | 544.76 ns | 4.22 | 0.08 | 0.0706 | 296 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **12345(...)12345 [40]** | **161.58 ns** | **1.509 ns** | **1.338 ns** | **161.86 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.0668** | **280 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [40] | 1,900.12 ns | 37.730 ns | 33.446 ns | 1,896.37 ns | 11.76 | 0.24 | 0.2956 | 1,240 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [40] | 1,399.98 ns | 27.838 ns | 77.602 ns | 1,370.01 ns | 9.27 | 0.28 | 0.5569 | 2,336 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [40] | 12,315.16 ns | 143.022 ns | 111.662 ns | 12,321.32 ns | 76.22 | 0.98 | 3.4637 | 14,520 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 12345(...)12345 [40] | 59.83 ns | 2.957 ns | 8.625 ns | 57.83 ns | 0.34 | 0.02 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [40] | 1,087.25 ns | 18.482 ns | 17.288 ns | 1,086.55 ns | 6.74 | 0.11 | 0.1678 | 704 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **12345(...)12345 [50]** | **197.47 ns** | **1.815 ns** | **1.417 ns** | **197.59 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.0763** | **320 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [50] | 2,666.97 ns | 22.475 ns | 21.023 ns | 2,665.74 ns | 13.51 | 0.16 | 0.4196 | 1,768 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [50] | 1,750.60 ns | 17.269 ns | 13.483 ns | 1,749.85 ns | 8.87 | 0.11 | 0.7782 | 3,256 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [50] | 15,840.75 ns | 315.818 ns | 569.485 ns | 15,549.61 ns | 79.38 | 2.94 | 5.0964 | 21,360 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 12345(...)12345 [50] | 44.87 ns | 0.809 ns | 0.756 ns | 45.09 ns | 0.23 | 0.00 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [50] | 1,626.71 ns | 27.600 ns | 23.047 ns | 1,623.62 ns | 8.24 | 0.14 | 0.2747 | 1,152 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **12345(...)12345 [75]** | **306.08 ns** | **4.371 ns** | **3.650 ns** | **305.57 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.1030** | **432 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [75] | 5,192.75 ns | 34.686 ns | 30.749 ns | 5,195.60 ns | 16.96 | 0.17 | 0.7629 | 3,208 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [75] | 3,988.09 ns | 271.305 ns | 799.948 ns | 3,794.99 ns | 10.89 | 2.50 | 1.4191 | 5,944 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [75] | 33,948.30 ns | 1,493.620 ns | 4,403.973 ns | 32,639.63 ns | 132.92 | 8.45 | 10.4370 | 43,848 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 12345(...)12345 [75] | 43.95 ns | 0.908 ns | 1.360 ns | 43.35 ns | 0.14 | 0.00 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 12345(...)12345 [75] | 3,529.34 ns | 68.576 ns | 60.791 ns | 3,531.11 ns | 11.54 | 0.20 | 0.5836 | 2,456 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **1234(...)2345 [100]** | **552.12 ns** | **32.468 ns** | **95.732 ns** | **533.47 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.1316** | **552 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [100] | 9,353.61 ns | 278.178 ns | 820.215 ns | 9,213.45 ns | 17.62 | 4.21 | 1.1902 | 5,000 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [100] | 3,949.08 ns | 49.055 ns | 45.886 ns | 3,945.01 ns | 8.32 | 1.34 | 2.1667 | 9,064 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [100] | 40,856.02 ns | 442.861 ns | 414.252 ns | 40,816.28 ns | 86.03 | 13.74 | 17.7002 | 74,120 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 1234(...)2345 [100] | 42.35 ns | 0.558 ns | 0.436 ns | 42.26 ns | 0.09 | 0.02 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [100] | 6,511.54 ns | 60.303 ns | 56.407 ns | 6,513.08 ns | 13.70 | 2.11 | 0.9766 | 4,112 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **1234(...)2345 [150]** | **734.17 ns** | **11.671 ns** | **9.746 ns** | **735.48 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.1831** | **768 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [150] | 18,963.26 ns | 291.798 ns | 272.948 ns | 18,927.82 ns | 25.76 | 0.43 | 2.2278 | 9,384 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [150] | 7,402.45 ns | 146.064 ns | 326.694 ns | 7,373.84 ns | 9.63 | 0.46 | 4.0283 | 16,848 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [150] | 96,553.68 ns | 3,203.319 ns | 9,344.232 ns | 94,618.21 ns | 124.75 | 3.00 | 37.7197 | 157,928 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 1234(...)2345 [150] | 43.73 ns | 0.847 ns | 0.792 ns | 43.57 ns | 0.06 | 0.00 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [150] | 13,799.37 ns | 181.226 ns | 169.519 ns | 13,831.45 ns | 18.75 | 0.27 | 1.9531 | 8,184 B |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **ToStringBenchmark** | **1234(...)2345 [200]** | **1,170.38 ns** | **22.340 ns** | **18.655 ns** | **1,167.00 ns** | **1.00** | **0.00** | **0.2365** | **992 B** |
| GetLengthDivisionBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [200] | 30,656.86 ns | 493.053 ns | 437.079 ns | 30,659.95 ns | 26.21 | 0.70 | 3.5400 | 14,896 B |
| GetLengthMultiplicationBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [200] | 9,459.47 ns | 115.420 ns | 102.317 ns | 9,419.28 ns | 8.09 | 0.17 | 6.3477 | 26,600 B |
| GetLengthAbsPowBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [200] | 124,083.76 ns | 2,093.310 ns | 1,748.008 ns | 124,681.07 ns | 106.03 | 1.39 | 65.1855 | 272,776 B |
| BigIntegerLog | 1234(...)2345 [200] | 50.15 ns | 1.029 ns | 1.338 ns | 49.84 ns | 0.04 | 0.00 | - | - |
| CountDigitsBenchmark | 1234(...)2345 [200] | 26,047.64 ns | 520.981 ns | 1,452.286 ns | 25,753.68 ns | 24.32 | 0.90 | 3.2043 | 13,416 B |

[image]

Comment: At least one answer that doesn’t ignore `Is there a more efficient way`

Comment: Would you mind adding my solution to this list too?

Comment: @MatthewLayton not at all. Happy to run the benchmarks again.

Comment: @MatthewLayton done. I would absolutely NOT recommend your solution :).

Comment: EEK! That looks awful! Thanks for adding. I'll go update my answer to reference these benchmarks.

Comment: Anyone want to try division by 1024 (effectively a bit shift by 10).  It's no an even multiple of 10, but damn close.

Comment: So, since you have 30k rep, I feel the need to point out that the output from your run is formatted in MarkDown (look at how the table is rendered).  Any reason you pasted an image of text rather than the text itself? :-)

Comment: @Flydog57 mostly because I just didn't think of it, but great suggestion! Added.

Comment: *"Anytime a question asks about "performance", it is always necessary to benchmark the approaches."* -- I would say that before benchmarking anything, it's more important the verify the correctness of the alternatives. There is little value at getting incorrect results, faster. If you don't care about correctness, then you can just `return 42`. It's blazingly fast, you can't beat that. Also I wouldn't trust a benchmark that uses a single input. Not all `BigInteger`s have 40 decimal digits. Some have less, some have much much more!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias completely fair. Those types of benchmarks just happen to be _very_ time intensive but for completeness, I've added additional results that still demonstrate very similar results for all inputs aside from very small numbers.

Comment: I've added a solution that uses bit-shifting.  It sacrifices correctness (it can easily underestimate the result by one), but it should be very fast.

Comment: It seems that the `BigIntegerLog` method takes constant time to compute, whatever input you throw at it. Which make it the obvious winner, assuming that the calculated result is correct.

Comment: I think you should also test the results, BigIntegerLog(1) return 0, BigIntegerLog(1000000000) returns 9. This method has issues with rounding errors. Probably the best solution would use GetBitLength  (but it only turned up in .Net 5)

Answer (score 4):

There's this:

```
static int GetLength(this BigInteger value)
{
    int result = 1;
    while (value >= 10)
    {
        result++;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I know it seems like the loop could be slow, but it's still probably faster than  `ToString()`, which thanks to localization/cultural issues is probably a LOT slower even than you'd expect.

Or we can invert it to use multiplication and count up, which might be faster depending on the instruction set of the computer, even though it needs an additional variable:

```
static int GetLength(this BigInteger value)
{
    BigInteger power = 10;
    int result = 1;
    while (power < value)
    {
        result++;
        power *= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally, I need to point out both of these assume positive values. I feel this is justified, because the original `ToString()` code would also return a count including the negative sign *which is system dependent*.

Windows lets me set the default negative sign to be any arbitrary string I want, and someone else logged into a different profile on the same computer could have a completely different setting here (thankfully, people hardly ever change this). The UI limits the number of characters you can use, but the registry location it writes to is much more forgiving for long negative strings.

Therefore, if the original code is allowed to be wrong for negative values, this code can to (and this is much easier to fix).

Comment: Thanks for this - really useful. I've also added an answer as I managed to derive something from your answer.

Comment: Beautiful! i know it will be A LOT of code but just in the aspect of processing efficient - is an endless switch case of (value > 1 && value < 10) and so on, will be faster?

Comment: This answer is MUCH less performant than either `BigInteger.ToString()` or `BigInteger.Log10()`. I added an answer with benchmarks that show just how much of a performance hit is caused by this approach.

Comment: Consider doing this with 1024 instead of 10.  I expect that the code handles division by a power of 2 as simply a bit shift (or, just do bit shifts).

Answer (score 2):

### DO NOT USE THIS!

Check the benchmarks produced by @David L - it's the worst performing.

Many thanks to @Joel Coehoorn, from whose answer I managed to derive this:

```cs
static int GetLength(BigInteger value)
{
    int result = 1;
    BigInteger ten = new(10);
    BigInteger absValue = BigInteger.Abs(value);

    while(BigInteger.Pow(ten, result) < absValue)
    {
         result++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Leaving it here for feedback (again, don't use it!)

---

### A Better Solution

As `Log10` seems to be the fastest solution, but requires rounding, I've tested the following solution over 50,000 BigInteger values:

```cs
static int GetLength(BigInteger value)
{
    double log10 = BigInteger.Log10(value);
    return (int) Math.Ceiling(log10) + 1;
}
```